# Ansible | Create symlink if directory is empty

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Create 404 link
      file:
        dest: /var/www/html/{{ item }}/images/index.html
        src: /var/www/html/404.html
        state: link
      with_items:
        - a
        - b
        - c
        - d
        - e
      # when: ???
...
```

**Now the task should run only if the `/var/www/html/{{ item }}/images` directory is empty.** How do I get this done? I've tried using the `find` module and `register`ing the output but wasn't successful in extracting the items (directories) which had no files in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: check contents of dir
      find:
        paths: "/var/www/html/{{ item }}/images/"
        patterns: "[A-Za-z0-9_-]+"
        use_regex: True
        file_type: any
        recurse: yes
      with_items:
        - a
        - b
        - c
        - d
        - e
      register: find_output

    - name: Create 404 link
      file:
        dest: /var/www/html/{{ item.item }}/images/index.html
        src: /var/www/html/404.html
        state: link
      with_items: "{{ find_output.results }}"
      when: item.matched == 0
...
```